# [GSI_LOGGER]: The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID. && Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400

Tags: django, static, client, google-ads-api

[[GSI_LOGGER]: The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuReV.png)

I have added "javascript_origins": [
"http://localhost",
"http://localhost:8000"
]

I don't uderstand Why am i gettingthis

The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID.

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>

{% load static %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '/js/app.js' %}"></script>


<h1>My Awesome App</h1>

<div id="g_id_onload"
 data-client_id="873307876888-9ht3ph1vm7l62ugtmos36fddrrm6bj5n.apps.googleusercontent.com"
 data-context="signin"
 data-ux_mode="popup"
 data-callback="handleLogin"
 data-auto_select="true"
 data-itp_support="true">
</div>

<div class="g_id_signin"
    data-type="standard"
    data-shape="rectangular"
    data-theme="outline"
    data-text="signin_with"
    data-size="large"
    data-logo_alignment="left">
</div>
```